# SQLite: Selecting the maximum corresponding value

Tags: sqlite, select, max

I have a table with three columns as follows:

```
id INTEGER    name TEXT    value REAL
```

How can I select the `value` at the maximum `id`?

Comment: The question does no specify explicitly that it is desired only one or several records. In the first case then the answer is quite trivial (@CL ... ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1), but it could be of interest to have more records if the maximum 'id' is repeated with different 'name'  and 'values'. In that case the correct answer would be (@sergi .... id == (SELECT max(id) FROM table))

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Get the records with the largest IDs first, then stop after the first record:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Above Query Searches n records, then arranges n records, then gets 1 record...?????? is this query efficient, it needs tuning. Below answer by @Newbie is much better in terms of efficiency.

Comment: In a LIMIT *n* query, SQLite keeps only the *n* largest rows while sorting. And if the column is indexed, no sorting is necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Just like the mysql, you can use `MAX()`

e.g.    `SELECT MAX(id) AS member_id, name, value FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME`

Comment: I want to select the value not id.

Comment: What if you want to select on the row that has the maximum of two different cells?

Comment: that select does not return the 'name' and 'value' of the record having the max id, but the max id and some "random" 'name' and 'value' of the table

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    SELECT value FROM table WHERE id==(SELECT max(id) FROM table));
```

Comment: `==` doesn't exists in SQL, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: this is the better answer. We cannot assume that id is unique and if there are more than one record having the maximum id this is the only SQL returning all records.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the query syntax :

```
String query = "SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id FROM mytable";
```

Comment: it only returns the max id but not the "value" of that max id. see the question